# Determine minimum values of a function

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Find the $x$ values that minimize the function $f(x)$.
$$
f(x) = e^x + \frac{1}{m}(x-4)^2
$$
I know I can determine the minimum values when the derivative of the function is $0$.
So  I have calculated the derivative
$$
f'(x) = e^x + \frac{2x}{m} - \frac{8}{m}
$$
But I do not know how to reflect $x$ when $f'(x)$ is $0$.

Comment: Your formula for the derivative is slightly incorrect. The constant term should be $8/m$, not $8m$

Comment: I have suppressed tag "derivatives" which deals with financial mathematics.

Comment: Why do you think this has a nice solution?

Comment: Additionally, there is no need to "reflect $x$" in order to find the minimum value. The minimum occurs either when $f'(x)$ is $0$ or at one of the endpoints of the interval under consideration.

Comment: When you graphic the function you can see that there is a minimum value but I do not know how to reflect x to find the x* that minimizes the function

Comment: x can take values from all R

Comment: You can observe that the derivative is monotonically increasing and that is negative when $x\to-\infty$ and positive when $x\to+\infty$. You can then conclude on the existence of an $x^*$ such that $f'(x^*)=0$. Moreover, since $f''(x^*)>0$, this is a minimum.

Comment: Are you trying to find an exact solution? If you only need an approximate solution, you can try using a numerical method, such as Newton's method.

Comment: If you want the exact solution, you will probably express it with the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: Yes. I need to find the exact x* that minimizes f(x). I am going to try your suggestions

Comment: Hey, dont think so completed using derivative just try m=1 then try 2 and try m=3 and and 4 understand the pattern!! Then try to use basic inequality argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe that the derivative is monotonically increasing and that is negative when $x\to-\infty$ and positive when $x\to+\infty$. You can then conclude on the existence of an $x^*$ such that $f'(x^*)=0$. Moreover, since $f''(x^*)>0$, this is a minimum.

The equation

$$f'(x^*) = e^{x^*} + \frac{2x^*}{m} - \frac{8}{m}=0$$

is a transcendental equation and so there will no closed-form solution for $x^*$ in terms of elementary functions. We can, however, express the real solution in terms of the Lambert-W function that expresses the solutions of equations of the form $xe^x=c$.

First let $y=2x^*/m+8/m$ and then $x^*=(my+8)/2$. Considering then $e^{-x^*}f'(x^*)=0$ and the previous change of variables yields

$$1+e^{-(my+8)/2}y=0.$$

This expression can be reformulated as

$$-\dfrac{my}{2}e^{-my/2}=\dfrac{m}{2}e^4.$$

Invoking now the Lambert W function, we get that

$$y = \dfrac{-2}{m}W_0(-me^4/2),$$

where $W_0$ is the principal branch of the Lambert W function. Finally,

$$x^*=-W(-me^4/2)+4,$$

which gives an explicit expression for $x^*$.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

@KBS gave the only explicit solution : $f(x)$ is minimum when $x=x_*=4-W\left(\frac{e^4 m}{2}\right)$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

This makes
$$f(x_*)=\frac 1 m W\left(\frac{e^4 m}{2}\right) \left(2+W\left(\frac{e^4 m}{2}\right)\right)$$

In year $2007$, Hoorfar and Hassani gave in [this paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/107_07_JIPAM/107_07_www.pdf) the following tight bounds $\forall x \geq e$
$$\log (x)-\log (\log (x))+\frac 12\frac{\log (\log (x))}{\log (x)}\leq W(x)\leq \log (x)-\log (\log (x))+\frac e {e-1}\frac{\log (\log (x))}{\log (x)}$$

This gives you a quick way to bound the value of $f(x_*)$.